How to use text expression to subset data
Suppose I read some file that contains operations to be made in a dataset, as an example
library(data.table)
dt = setDT(mtcars)
exp1 = "cyl == 8 & mpg > 16"
exp2 = "cyl == 6 & mpg < 20"

in this case exp1 and exp2 are read from a file as text, is there a way to do something like this
dt[eval(exp1)]
dt[eval(exp2)]

use the text expression to subset data and make other data transformations?
EDIT:
If I do something like
exp1 = quote(cyl == 8 & mpg > 16)
dt[eval(exp1)]

it works, but how I chance the data that is stored to text to use this quote approach? Also is there any problem using this method?

Typically variables store data and functions store code (e.g. as explained in https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). What you're trying to do is possible of course, but it will ultimately lead to issues/problems/errors as your code gets more complicated. Is there some reason that's not obvious from this minimal example why you don't want to just use functions for each 'step' in your 'pipeline'?

dt[eval(str2lang(exp1))] but see section on parse / eval in vignette("datatable-programming").

@jared_mamrot  I'm trying create an integration between a R code and an excel spreadsheet, so users that not use R can manipulate and process some data that doesn't fit directly into excel. Then the idea is translate the expressions passed in the excel sheet into R code

I had tested on dt[eval(parse(text = exp1))] which also works but as noted by @lotus in the vignette it's not the best way. The answer below using do.call seems a nice approach

That makes sense Rooh; in that case I would use G. Grothendieck's approach. Good luck!

To do this without explicitly using eval (which is often frowned upon) use do.call as shown in the following examples:
1) [ To use [.data.table try the following:
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)
exp1 <- "cyl == 8 & mpg > 16"

do.call("[", list(dt, str2lang(exp1)))

giving
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:  18.7     8 360.0   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2
2:  16.4     8 275.8   180  3.07 4.070 17.40     0     0     3     3
3:  17.3     8 275.8   180  3.07 3.730 17.60     0     0     3     3
4:  19.2     8 400.0   175  3.08 3.845 17.05     0     0     3     2

2) subset  Using subset would also work:
do.call(subset, list(dt, str2lang(exp1)))

3) lm/plot If the objective is to subsequently feed the subset into lm or plot then the subseting and call to lm can be done all at once by passing each of the 3 arguments to lm as separate components of the list passed to do.call . Again, we have managed to avoid any explicit eval calls. (This would work with just dt in place of quote(dt) but the Call: line would then be messed up.)
do.call("lm", list(mpg ~ ., quote(dt), subset = str2lang(exp1)))

## Call:
## lm(formula = mpg ~ ., data = dt, subset = cyl == 8 & mpg > 16)
...snip...

or with plot
do.call(plot, list(mpg ~ disp, dt, subset = str2lang(exp1)))

4) tidyverse With tidyverse we can use !!parse_expr(...)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

 dt %>% filter(!!parse_expr(exp1))


Here is another solution. Note that you don't need to use eval When working with data.table programming interface (argument env).
library(data.table)
exp1 = "cyl == 8 & mpg > 16"

dt[.i, env = list(.i = str2lang(exp1))]

     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:  18.7     8 360.0   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2
2:  16.4     8 275.8   180  3.07 4.070 17.40     0     0     3     3
3:  17.3     8 275.8   180  3.07 3.730 17.60     0     0     3     3
4:  19.2     8 400.0   175  3.08 3.845 17.05     0     0     3     2

